# how to conver json array to html

Tags: javascript, json

[image: json format]

Hello community, you can't help me to convert json array to html table.

Comment: You need to include the exact HTML you want and also the code you have tried so far to solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

You can consider creating those elements dynamically using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement). After that, inject to DOM using [`node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

```js
const scoreFinal = [
  { id: '7', nombre: 'Bruce Banner', puntaje: '90' },
  { id: '5', nombre: 'Saul Mendez', puntaje: '80' }
];

for (const { id, nombre, puntaje } of scoreFinal) {
  const tdId = document.createElement('td');
  tdId.innerText = id;
  const tdNombre = document.createElement('td');
  tdNombre.innerText = nombre;
  const tdPuntaje = document.createElement('td');
  tdPuntaje.innerText = puntaje;

  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  row.appendChild(tdId);
  row.appendChild(tdNombre);
  row.appendChild(tdPuntaje);
  document.getElementById('scoreFinal').appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="scoreFinal"><tr><th>Id</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Puntaje</th></tr></table>
```

Comment: You could consider adding a header row with `<tr><th>Id</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Puntaje</th></tr>` to the initial table so the columns are labeled

Comment: Thanks @mousetail! Added the header for clarity